# Finalizing cursor on null that that has not been deactivated or closed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

In my application, I tried using the following codes to validate the user email address exists in database or not. If the user email address does not exist it will insert the user info into database. But this message appeared and I cant get the user info into the database. I not really sure what the issue here.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(){
   helper = new DBHelper(this);


    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(useremail.length() == 0){

                alertMessage = "Please enter Email Address.";
                dialogBox();
            }
            else if (password.length() == 0){

                alertMessage = "Please enter Password.";
                dialogBox();
            }

            else {
                emailid = useremail.getText().toString();
                userpassword = password.getText().toString();

               if(!helper.emailidChecking(emailid)){
                    helper.insert_wbm_user(emailid);
               }
               else{
                    alertMessage="User email exists";
                    dialogBox();
               }
           }
        }
     });
}





public void onDestroy(){
       super.onDestroy();
       helper.close();
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
    public boolean emailidChecking(String emailid) throws SQLException
{
    helper = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.i(TAG, "emailidChecking:" +emailid);
    Cursor c = helper.rawQuery("SELECT * from user_info where emailid='"+emailid+"'", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0){  
        //not in db
        Log.i(TAG, "getCount = 0");
        return true;
    }
    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }
    if (helper!=null){
        helper.close();
    }

    return false;

}


public long insert_user_info(String emailid) {

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("emailid", emailid);

    Log.i(TAG, "insert db");

    long createdinMsg = getWritableDatabase().insert("user_info", "emailid", cv);
    return createdinMsg;

}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-29 10:03:12.007: D/Cursor(2143): Database path: /data/data/com.ff.fbin/databases/wbdb.db
01-29 10:03:12.007: D/Cursor(2143): Table name   : null
01-29 10:03:12.007: D/Cursor(2143): SQL          : SQLiteQuery: SELECT * from user_info where emailid='asd@hotmail.com'
01-29 10:03:12.007: I/dalvikvm(2143): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
01-29 10:03:12.007: I/dalvikvm(2143): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405b07e8 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
01-29 10:03:12.011: I/dalvikvm(2143):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:620)
01-29 10:03:12.011: I/dalvikvm(2143):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: I don't really get it. Specifically which part do you mean?

Comment: I mean the extra blank lines and the indenting. The code you have given won't compile as there are missing braces.

Comment: Sorry, I just post out the codes related to the error that's why there are some extra black lines. Updated the code, that's basically the main part of the code.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable (in fact encouraged) to remove code from your post. However, that typically means deleting the whole line and not leaving a blank. Also, you should be careful that you don't remove too many curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> public boolean emailidChecking(String emailid) throws SQLException
>  {
> helper = this.getReadableDatabase();
> Log.i(TAG, "emailidChecking:" +emailid);
> Cursor c = helper.rawQuery("SELECT * from user_info where emailid='"+emailid+"'", null);
> try
> {
>     if(c.getCount()==0){  
>         //not in db
>        Log.i(TAG, "getCount = 0");
>        c.close();   <-------- Close the cursor here.
>        return true;
>      }
>  }
>  finally
>  {
>      c.close();
>      if (helper!=null){
>         helper.close();
>        }
>    }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean emailidChecking(String emailid) throws SQLException
{
   helper = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Log.i(TAG, "emailidChecking:" +emailid);
   Cursor c = helper.rawQuery("SELECT * from user_info where emailid='"+emailid+"'", null);
   if(c.getCount()==0){  
    //not in db
       Log.i(TAG, "getCount = 0");
       c.close();
       return true;
   }
   if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
       c.close();
   }
   if (helper!=null){
       helper.close();
   }

   return false;

}
```

Problem solved by including `c.close();` before `return true;`